# XSLT - Discard child if last char of id is equal to

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt

Good Evening,

I'm having trouble with XSLT, I've got to check/modify a project started 3 yrs ago.

At the moment the apply-template is formatted like this `<xsl:apply-templates select="foo[make != 'Contoso'][prices/listPrice != '0.0'][type = 'USED']"/>`.

If the last char of ID `foo` is P, I need to discard it and go to the next one.

I've searched various solutions, but no one worked.

EDIT:

I'm using the 1.0 XSLT version

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a sample of your XML with `foo` in. It is not clear with "ID" is a child node, or attribute, of `foo` at the moment. Can you also say whether you can use XSLT 2.0 too, as you may be able to use `EndsWith` in that case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your input XML is something like this:

```
<root>
  <foo ID="XXXP">
    <make>Abcd</make>
    <prices>
      <listPrice>5000.0</listPrice>
    </prices>
    <type>USED</type>
  </foo>
  <foo ID="XXX">
    <make>Xyz</make>
    <prices>
      <listPrice>2000.0</listPrice>
    </prices>
    <type>USED</type>
  </foo>
</root>
```

To introduce your modification, add `[not(ends-with(@ID, 'P'))]` to the
`select` attribute, meaning:

- Additional predicate (`[...]`).
- You refer to `ID` attribute of the current element (`foo`).
- You require that this `ID` does not end with `P`.

As you didn't specify the XSLT version, I used version 2.0.

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/3MP2uBF/1

**Additional remark:** I think, a better way to check for *price != 0* is:

```
[number(prices/listPrice) != 0]
```

(I included it in the above mentioned example).

If you are limited to version 1.0, use respective equivalent expression
(version 1.0 has no `ends-with` function).

Comment: Yep, I'm using the 1.0, the equivalent expression is complicated or not?

Comment: In **XSLT 1.0**, in your case, you have to "extract" the last char of `ID`
and check whether it is `P`. So the equivalent expression (the whole predicate) is: `[substring(@ID, string-length(@ID)) != 'P']`. Note that this time I wrote `!=`, so `not` is not needed.

Comment: I've done a few tests, but the expression is not filtering my XML, now the apply template is `<xsl:apply-templates select="foo[substring(@id, string-length(@id)) != 'P'][make != 'Contoso'][number(prices/listPrice) != 0.0][type = 'USED']"/>` but i still find ids with an ending P. I'm sure I'm missing the point of it

Comment: In your post you wrote "ID", but in the previous comment "id". This is not the same. Another question: I assumed that "ID" (or "id") is an **attribute** of *foo*. Check whether this "ID" is really attribute. Or maybe child **element**?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I wrote using caps in the question.
The  XML father look like this 

`<root><foo id="12345P"><make>Contoso</make></foo></root>`

Comment: To be sure that my solution works, check the working example I mentioned in the answer. Experiment with changing "id" attribute and adding additional *foo* elements, to see the result. Look also at your script. Maybe it contains other *apply-templates*, which serve as a "backdoor" copying unwanted *foo* elements. And change "@ID" to "@id".